# Opening multiple notebooks in Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: installation

I installed mathematica on Linux mint cinnamon latest edition and it works, but with one annoying issue: when there is a notebook open and I click on another notebook in the file manager, a whole new instance of the mathematica application launches (with a new startpage that needs to be closed separately at the end). How can I launch the new notebook from the file manager in the already running app? Is it not a problem to have two instances of mathematica running? I think it affects the performance or the interface is laggier if there are two.

Comment: Use hotkeys, `Ctrl-N` or `Ctrl-O` or menu. It might be a problem to run several copies of WM if the number of kernels in your license is limited. Note, having separate copies allows to run tasks simultaneously which might be desired.

Comment: @I.M. Have been doing that for the moment. Ran into the kernel issue too. But yeah I see the reason why someone would want to launch every notebook in a different instance. However is there a way to change settings so that it doesn't happen, and when I click on a nb file it opens in the already running mathematica?

Comment: You may want to modify the `.desktop` file for your Mathematica shortcut to add `-sl` to the command flags (the `Exec` key in that file), although I don't know for sure that the `.desktop` file handles double-clicking of related files.

Comment: @ Szabolcs yeah it does, thank you. @CarlLange trying this now, but where to find these config files? Anyway -sl is the flag I needed.

Comment: Usually in `/usr/share/applications/` or `/usr/local/share/applications/`. Depending on what you have installed, it might be called `wolfram-mathematica12.desktop` or similar. You might need to restart your X session (like, by logging in and out) to apply the changes. (Top tip, you can also add `-nosplash` to prevent the splash screen showing, if you want)